# How to define DATASET for created highChart in SPAGOBI project using SPAGOBI Studio

Tags: spagobi

I need to implement Highcharts in SpagoBI.
I am using SPAGOBI studio 5.1.

Steps:

1. Create New SPAGOBI project.
2. Then Business Analysis > Chart > Chart With HighChart
3. Then defined all the atrributes like name, color etc.
4. After successfully deploying in the SPAGOBI server i am not seeing any chart appearing in SERVER. It shows just a name of chart alone as below since we did not set any values to the axis attributes.
5. Please let me know where to define the values for the axis of chart in studio. Attaching the image for your reference.
   [image]
   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can define values and others configurations of axis in "Axis Section" in SpagoBi Studio, with the chart editor.

Or you can edit this document on a text editor and set what you need, note that the document is in XML format.

In my case i begin editing in chart editor and after i edit on a text editor, because sometimes SpagoBi Studio do not generate the XML correct.

Hopes that helps. Cheers.